# Can I use two different look and feels in the same Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I'm using the Flamingo ribbon and the Substance Office 2007 look and feel.

Of course now **every** control has this look and feel, even those on dialog boxes.

What I want is something like in Office 2007, where the ribbons have their Office 2007 look, but other controls keep their native Vista/XP look.

Is it possible to assign certain controls a different look and feel? Perhaps using some kind of chaining or a proxy look and feel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just discovered: Since [Substance 5.0](https://substance.dev.java.net/release-info/5.0/release-info.html) the [SKIN_PROPERTY](https://substance.dev.java.net/docs/clientprops/SkinProperty.html) is available.

It allows assigning different skins to different `JRootPanes` (i.e. `JDialog`, `JFrame`, `JInternalFrame`)

A little trick: I override `JInternalFrame` to remove the extra border and the title pane so that it looks just like a borderless panel. That way it is possible to create the impression, that different parts of a form/dialog have different looks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a library which will automaticaly change the look and feel. I am not sure it this will done for every component in a different way, but you should take a look at it. [pbjar.org](http://www.pbjar.org/dynamicloca.html)

This book should be useful if you want to go deep into look and feel [/java-look-and-feel-design-guidelines-second-edition](http://2020ok.com/books/29/java-look-and-feel-design-guidelines-second-edition-37029.htm)

I would be glad to see some code example, if someone can write it, feel free to get starting.

**EDIT:**

In this forum thread [Thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=236002&tstart=0) i found the following description

> Swing uses a Look & Feel (a PLAF).
>   PLAFs aren't attached on a per-JFrame
>   level. They are attached on a per-VM
>   level. It is almost impossible to mix
>   PLAFs within one application. I have
>   seen a few attempts, all failed.

Comment: It's actually per-AppContext. You should be able to have applets on different sites having different PL&Fs installed.

Answer (score 1):

Swing unfortunately does lots of "psuedo-global" things behind the scenes. AFAIK, the only way to do it consistently is to use the private `AppContext` API. Each `AppContext` has its own event dispatch thread and other "psuedo-globals".