# Can groovy's swingbuilder get more than one look and feel in a Java swing application?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, groovy, look-and-feel

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446056/can-i-use-two-different-look-and-feels-in-the-same-swing-application), it would seem that normally you can't mix-and-match look and feels in the same swing app.

However, we've been using groovy's swingbuilder to handle all of our GUI code, and groovy seems to do enough black magic that this seemed in the Realms of the Possible.

Can swingbuilder set the LaF at, say, the Frame level?

(Specifically, the main app opens a specific sub-utility in it's own frame, rather than a dialog box.  This child frame and all of its children are what I'd like to have in a different LaF from the main app frame.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the answer is "no."