# how to have multiple look and feel in a single swing application

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jeditorpane, nimbus

I am using Nimbus look and feel in my Swing project.

Its displaying the excellent look in the project but `JEditorPane` is not displaying the proper font format when applying Nimbus look and feel

So is it possible to have multiple look and feels for single application? By default the project takes the look and feel applied on the main screen. Can it change the look and feel in between the project execution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446056/can-i-use-two-different-look-and-feels-in-the-same-swing-application

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying the proper font format"? Can you provide a example?

Comment: I am displaying html files in jeditorpane the the font in jedtitorpane is not the same as it is actually in the original html files

Comment: @adeshsingh have you tried a different look and feel?

Comment: yes, this is possible,for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` and `JEditorPane` with hardcoded value for `JEditorPane`s content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest is technically possible, but the approach is fragile for any but the most well-encapsualted default used by a well-behaved UI delegate implementation. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262706/230513), a borrowed `JTree` icon is shown. For your application, the relevant key is "EditorPane.font". If you change it, some things to keep in mind:

- Prefer a logical font family to a physical font, e.g. `Font.SANS_SERIF` or `Font. DIALOG`.
- Consider using the `deriveFont()` method to alter the existing default.
- Test extensively on your target platform(s).
- Consider an alternate approach, where possible.

[image]

Comment: +1 but I can see another issue there, not sure what (with Html styles, version and support in Java) OP meaning with `I am displaying html files in jeditorpane the the font in jedtitorpane is not the same as it is actually in the original html files`

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah, good point, thank you for commenting; HTML support is [limited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785121/230513) and fonts vary by platform. Maybe adesh singh can edit the question to clarify.